# How to use a loop in a shell script for this hive query?

Tags: hive, sh

```
  date=20190901


  hql="select DISTINCT content from ods_tblog_content where dt==$dt"

  hive -e "$hql"> data/"content_$dt"
```

This script gets data by a specific date, where I specified the date as 'Sept. 1, 2019'. How can I use a loop to get content for a specific date of each month? That is:

```
20190901
20190801
20190701
20190620
20190515
```

I feels like I should put these dates into an array and use a loop to do that? I am new to shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea. Here is a script to help with the syntax.

```
#!/bin/sh
hql="select DISTINCT content from ods_tblog_content where dt=${dt}"
#Array for desired dates
dates=(20190901 20190801 20190701 20190620 20190515)
for dt in ${dates[@]}
do 
hive -e "$hql" > /data/"content_${dt}"
done
```

Comment: Do you need a comma in dates=()? It gets a syntax error.

Comment: no, that is how an array is declared. where was the syntax error?

Comment: OK, it doesn't like a space within the (), which is strange.